# How to change checkbox like this?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I need to change checkbox from    [image] 
to [image]

Comment: put your .xml or style of checkbox

Comment: i have only normal checkbox i don't know how to do that that's why i am asking

Comment: did you tried   `android:buttonTint="@color/CHECK_COLOR"`

Comment: yes but the tick mark color does not changed

Comment: see my answer to change color of tick mark

Comment: set accent color as the required color in your application theme.

Answer (score 0):

I found that to change color of tick mark you have to put selectors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

In xml:

```
<CheckBox
   android:id="@+id/cb"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:button="@drawable/your_selector"/>
```

Comment: You can set Color also in place of drawables.

Answer (score 0):

create xml file

**coustom_check_box.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

         <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
         <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />

    </selector>
```

In checkbox  `set android:button`  property to the  custom_checkbox_design.xml  drawable  like
`android:button="@drawable/coustom_check_box"`

```
                <CheckBox
                   android:id="@+id/checkBoxCustomized1"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="Coustom Checkbox"
                   android:checked="true"
                   android:button="@drawable/coustom_check_box"
                   android:textSize="20dp" />
```

**icons**

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share the drawabl files

Comment: added but in your case you use your own icons.

Comment: @EbinFrancis is your issue fixed?

Comment: i customise the button in xml layout but it could not be show  in the activity xml file

Comment: can get you exactly? whats the `it could be show the activity xml`?

Comment: this is my xml file checked<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFD0305" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFD0305" />
</shape>

Comment: and normal <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid
        android:color="#fff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFEB4715" />
</shape>

Comment: cant you use images ?

Comment: not images its xml designs for better clarity can you have any idea to do with it

Comment: you cant use colors in `checkbox` as drawable go for an other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable custom_cheackbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item   android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_not_selected"android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_selected"      android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_not_selected"/>    
</selector>
```

add your custom background inside custom_checkbox `android:button="@drawable/custom_cheackbox"`

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```